# Calculating the divergence of static electric field without making the dependency argument?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, differentiation, gauss-law, calculus

This question is a follow up on this old post here [Divergence of electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/344984/)

(So this may seem dumb...)

When calculating the divergence of a field point through the following equation, where $\left(\vec{\mathbf{\gamma}}=\vec{r}-\vec r'\right)$:
$$\nabla_r \cdot \mathbf  E(\vec r)=\int_{\text{all space}} \nabla_r\cdot\left(\frac{\vec{\gamma}}{\gamma^2}\right) \rho({\vec r'}) d\tau'$$

Suppose I just mindlessly calculate the intergrand by product rule **without considering the dependency of $\nabla_r$**, then
$$\nabla_r\cdot\left[\frac{\vec{\gamma}}{\gamma^2}\rho({\vec r'})\right]= \left(\frac{\partial\frac{\vec{\gamma} }{\gamma^2}}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial\frac{\vec{\gamma} }{\gamma^2}}{\partial y}\vec{j}+\frac{\partial\frac{\vec{\gamma}}{\gamma^2}}{\partial z}\vec{k}\right)\cdot\rho({\vec r'}) + \left(\frac{\vec{\gamma} }{\gamma^2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\rho(\vec r')}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial\rho(\vec r')}{\partial y}\vec{j}+\frac{\partial\rho(\vec r')}{\partial z}\vec{k}\right)$$

To get the correct result, the last term of the above equation needs to be zero
$$\frac{\partial\rho(\vec r')}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial\rho(\vec r')}{\partial y}\vec{j}+\frac{\partial\rho(\vec r')}{\partial z}\vec{k}=0$$

Let $\rho(\vec r')=|\rho(\vec r')|\cdot\vec r_u'$, where $\vec r_u'$ is the unit vector of $\vec r'$, then
$$\frac{\partial|\rho(\vec r')|}{\partial x}\vec{i}~\vec{r_u}'+\frac{\partial|\rho(\vec r')|}{\partial y}\vec{j}~\vec{r_u}'+\frac{\partial|\rho(\vec r')|}{\partial z}\vec{k}~\vec{r_u}'=0$$

At this point, how am I suppose to show the above equation is zero if I force myself to just calculate it without making the dependency argument？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence is calculated with respect to $\vec r$, not $\gamma$. $\gamma$ is defined through a dummy variable so it cannot be used outside the RHS integral. Now, it becomes obvious that $\nabla_r \rho(\vec r') =0$, because $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$ are independent variables.

Comment: I get the point, but what I am wondering is if I insist on decomposing (I know its kind of dumb) $\nabla_r \rho(\vec r')$ to $$\frac{\partial|\rho(\vec r')|}{\partial x}\vec{i}~\vec{r_u}'+\frac{\partial|\rho(\vec r')|}{\partial y}\vec{j}~\vec{r_u}'+\frac{\partial|\rho(\vec r')|}{\partial z}\vec{k}~\vec{r_u}'=0,$$ how do I also see from the decomposed equation that it is zero?

Comment: Each partial derivative above is equal to zero on its own. You may see it as follows $\vec{r'} = (x', y', z') = \sum_i r'_i \hat e_i$ (for brevity I set $r_1=x$, $r_2=y$, $r'_1=x'$, $r'_2=y'$ and so on.  $\partial_{r_i}(r'_j) = 0$ because they are independent. Thus $\partial_{r_i} (\vec {r'}) = 0$ and consequently $\partial_{r_i} f(\vec{r'}) =0$, where $f$ is any function of position.

Comment: But what exactly is $x_i'$ though? Isn't $\vec r'$ also on the same x-y-z coordinate system as $\vec r$ (because the source point and field point are both placed in the same coordinate system)? If I walk along, say x-axis while letting y & z fixed, I feel like I can observe both the change of charge density and field??

Comment: Imagine that you vary $x$ with $y$, $z$ and $\vec{r'}$ fixed. Does the density $\rho(\vec {r'} )$ change? No, it doesn't because the $\vec{r'}$ is fixed; the density $\rho(\vec{r})$ varies but it doesn't matter because it's not what we are calculating.

Comment: I see, I should consider $\vec r, ~\vec r' \in R^3$ as two variables just like $x, ~y \in R$